# How does pairwise comparison training work in XGBoost XGBRanker?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, ranking, training-data

I'm interested in learning to rank with pairwise comparison. While working on this I found that XGBoost has a model called XGBRanker which works very well.
I want to find out how the XGBRanker manages the training data to get such low memory usage and great results?(It uses LambdaMART I believe) 
I imagine it must be some kind of lookup table for the features and maybe making the pairs iteratively or not using all possible permutations with different labels within one group.

I tried looking through the [source code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/a1d23f6613200b35d178e02202c3dbb104fa7bc6/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L1482) but everything keeps referring to some other XGBoost method and I haven't been able to understand it so far.

I would like to create a similar method to train NNs for pairwise comparison but handling the training data has been a huge hurdle so far.
So more generally my Question would be: How are the pairs created in pairwise ranking anlgorithms?(RankNet,LambdaNet and so on) Are all pairs used? Only a percentage? Is there some other way of doing this? If you're working with >100.000 items you would easily get into the range of hundreds of millions.

I hope someone has some information about this or knows who might.

Comment: I think a better place to ask this would be https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you might wanna take a look at [input for ranking xgboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain) and [learning to rank xgboost-sklearn wrapper](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/rank)